# Weblogic Xquery exception difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, exception, weblogic, xquery, osb

First the setup: I am currently working on developing a test framework for testing XQuery-transformations intended to run in an OSB.

The framework is written in Java and uses the original OSB jars to execute the transformations.

The problem is when getting an error message the result differs between Linux (CI/CD) and Windows (local)

Error message on Linux:

> weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryDynamicException: {err}XP0021: "--": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date: error: date: Invalid date value: --

Error message on Windows:

> weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryDynamicException: {err}XP0021: [PX]["--": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date: error: date: Invalid date value: -- ä]

As you can see on Windows the error messages is using a complete different format. Now I am wondering if there are some settings to choose the format or if a have to use different methods of parsing the messages on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Is it really wise to be parsing error messages in a test framework? It seems a recipe for having a large number of spurious test failures and for a lot of effort spent keeping the tests abreast of changes in the software.

Comment: @MichaelKay one main requirement is to support negative test cases. So i have to check if the expected error message is equal to the given one. Or I have to risk false positives just looking for a general error.

Comment: The way we do this is to catch the exception and compare the error code with the expected error, not to parse the error message that is designed for human consumption. Alternatively just do a partial match on the message, for example `contains('XP0021')`.

Comment: I look at how detailed the messages must be in order to be correctly identified.Thanks for the advice

Comment: The error message is practically the same, not complete different? You could easily fix this with a pattern. Abstract example: "abc.package.Exception*error message*"